# want to know how many days remain of course duration in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to know that how can I get that **how many days are left** in course duration.

`course-duration` is just a column and hold an integer in database like `30`.

I want to compare `course-duration` with `created_at` and return me that left days in laravel.

```
id  username  course   course-duration(days)    created_at
---------------------------------------------------------------------
1   krish     SSB      14                       2018-11-19
---------------------------------------------------------------------
2   Brij      SSB      30                       2018-11-18
---------------------------------------------------------------------
3   Sagar     SSB      90                       2018-11-15
```

I want to get remaining days of the course after comparing `course-duration` with `created_at`.

Comment: I advice you to read [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: share some data, and expected results,  and also add some code which you have tried

Comment: SELECT DATE_ADD(created_at, INTERVAL -30 DAY) as date_end FROM your_table;

Answer (score 1):

You can get the remain days like this:

```
\DB::statement("SELECT (course-duration - DATEDIFF(NOW(), created_at)) remained FROM your_table");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Carbon to get the value of days between created_at and now

```
$diff_from_now = Carbon::parse($course->created_at)->diffInDays();
$course_duration = $course->duration;
$remaining_days = $course_duration- $diff_from_now;
```

Comment: In Laravel `created_at` is an instance of `Carbon` when retrieved from DB, so there is no need to parse it into a `Carbon` object again. you can use `$course->created_at->diffInDays();`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
   Select sub(course-duration - DATE(created_at)) as left_days from table_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just define a method in your `Course` model to calculate remaining days of each course:

```
class Course extends Model
{

    public function remainingDays() {
        return $this->course-duration - $this->created_at->diffInDays(Carbon::now());
    }

}
```

And to get remaining days of every course:

```
$course->remainingDays();
```